# List or IEnumerable for .NET Core Model?

Tags: list, asp.net-core, .net-core, model, entity-framework-core

Let's say I have a view with a model defined as `@model IEnumerable<ViewModel>` On the controller, this data is provided by entity framework and is thus an `IQueryable`.

I want to iterate through the data like this:

```
@if (Model != null && Model.Count() > 0)
{
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.firstProp
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.secondProp
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
else
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            No data to display.
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

I only want to iterate if there is at least one item, otherwise I want to show a different message. Because I'm using an `IEnumerable`, checking the count requires a trip to the database, and a second trip to iterate the foreach loop. I could always use a `List` instead, but I almost always see models defined using `IEnumerable`. Is using `List` a good solution, or should `IEnumerable` always be used when defining models?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First the difference between `List<T>`, `IEnumerable<T>` and `IQueryable<T>`.
The content of `List<T>` will always be loaded into memory, because it uses an array in the background.

---

The content of `IEnumerable<T>` will only load the requested item into the memory. Compiler sets up a state machine during compiling a method with `IEnumerable<T>` that has a `yield return T`. So only one item at a time will be loaded into memory in this case.

---

`IQueryable<T>` is "special" version of `IEnumerable<T>`. Specifically designed to query data sources, and implemented by data providers. Like EF, NHibernate. So when you tell EF to fetch the data with `.ToListAsync<T>()` EF will only then go the databas and execute the generated query.
See the docs for more info about `IQueryable<T>`.

---

Personly I use `ICollection<T>` with HasSet implementation to improve sorting and querying in memory.
For example:

```
public class MyModel 
{
   public ICollection<SomeSubModel> SomeSubModels { get; private set; } = new HasSet<SomeSubModel>();
}
```

(Additional if you have a large list it is good practice to use pagination.)

Comment: I do have pagination in place (15 rows max) so using a list and storing the data in memory probably isn't an issue, but I could also use an ICollection like you said.

Comment: That is good. Pagination is really good practice, specially if the API has max page size check as well. Note the private set. Hiding the set can prevent from unwanted logical bugs like trying to populate the list not from the db or accidentally overwriting the list. The initialization ensures that you won't run into a null ref exception and you only need to check the count of the list.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [nice article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/difference-between-iqueryable-and-ienumerable-while-working-in-linq/), you can check it, it explores the usages of IEnumerable, IList, and IQueryable, differences between them:

- *IEnumerable is useful when we want to iterate the collection of objects which deals with in-process memory.*
- *IQueryable is useful when we want to iterate a collection of objects which deals with ad-hoc queries against the data source or remote database, like SQL Server.*
- *IList is useful when we want to perform any operation like Add,Remove or Get item at specific index position in the collection.*

Personally, I prefer to use the ICollection in the data model, and use it to read/update the related entities from the database. Besides, we all should know that IQueryable is inherited from IEnumerable, so whatever IEnumerable can do, we can achieve with IQueryable as well.

```
public class Course
{  
    public int CourseID { get; set; }  
    public ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CourseAssignment> CourseAssignments { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in the controller, use the ToList or ToListAsync method to return the data to view.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var courses = _context.Courses
        .Include(c => c.Department)
        .AsNoTracking();
    return View(await courses.ToListAsync());
}
```

Finally, use IEnumerable to display the model.

```
@model IEnumerable<ContosoUniversity.Models.Course>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        }
```